# Syntax error in from clause of pass-through query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2016, pass-through

A pass-through SQL fails in MS Access 2016 VBA with the error `Syntax error in From clause` but executes OK in SQL Server on Azure.

I have in an MS Access 2016 VBA code of a Form a query definition named Qdf. The query set up in VBA is a pass-through query that connects to an SQL Server database in Azure. The connection string is copied from another piece of code where this works OK. `Returnsrecords property = True`.

When the code tries to populated the Qdf.SQL string it fails with the message

> "Syntax error in From Clause".

When I then debug and print the string that defines the SQL property in the Immediate (Debug) window, copy that printed string to a query SQL Server Management Studio on Azure, and then execute the query it just works.
So my conclusion is that the query is correct but somehow MS Access doesn't want to understand that.

In the code below:

- RepositoryDB_Name - holds the name of the database in SQL Server, -
- ArrAccountName(i) - holds the UserID,
- ArrAccountPassword(i) - the password of the User
- ResourceList - holds in this test at runtime 'Operational Data Store', 'MS MDS Master Data'.

The content of RepositoryDB_Name and Resourcelist comes from / is built up from content in Azure.

```
Debug.Print 

"SELECT * FROM [" & RepositoryDB_Name & "].[scan].[All Data Scope] WHERE [Database Business Name] IN (" & ResourceList & ");"
```

results in

```
"SELECT * FROM [DB_DEV].[scan].[All Data Scope] WHERE [Database Business Name] IN ('Operational Data Store', 'MS MDS Master Data')"
```

When the content of this string is copied into a query in SQL Server it works fine. 
[All Data Scope] is a view stored in the SQL Server database on Azure.

I have also tried by pasting the full [All Data Scope] Query in the SQL and then add the condition.
Again the resulting SQL string from the debugger (with only SQL Server tables in the FROM Clause) works fine on SQL Server when you paste the debugged value in a query on SQL Server Management Studio. 
This time I get the "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" message. 
So also here the query seems OK for SQL Server, but MS Access believes it to be incorrect...

How can this be resolved?
Is it a bug, or did I miss something?

```
ConnStr = "ODBC;Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=" & _
                   RepositoryServer & ";DATABASE=" & RepositoryDB_Name & ";UID=" & ArrAccountName(i) & ";PWD=" & ArrAccountPassword(i) & _
                   ";Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;"
        Set Qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
        Qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & RepositoryDB_Name & "].[scan].[All Data Scope] WHERE [Database Business Name] IN (" & ResourceList & ");"
        Qdf.Connect = ConnStr
```

Comment: Careful, that looks very open to injection. If you're using dynamic SQL you should be properly quoting your objects and properly parametrising your `WHERE`.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you assign `Qdf.Connect` before `Qdf.SQL`?

Comment: Yes, it makes THE difference. Now it does work. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error occurs because `FROM [DB_DEV].[scan].[All Data Scope]` is not valid in Access SQL.

Avoid that error by assigning the QueryDef's `.Connect` value before you assign its `.SQL` property value.

```vb
Qdf.Connect = ConnStr
Qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & RepositoryDB_Name & "].[scan].[All Data Scope] WHERE [Database Business Name] IN (" & ResourceList & ");"
```

That way, Access will realize the query is to be run in some other DBMS and not attempt to check whether the SQL statement is valid Access SQL.